# Touchscreen calibration troubles in Windows 8.1 using Eyefinity

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, touchscreen, eyefinity

I'm using Radeon Eyefinity to make a single desktop display of 3 monitors side by side.
Problem is, when setting up the touchscreen, windows 8.1 thinks that that's just one monitor, so when you set it up to calibrate the touch 'space', the touch on the first screen is represented by an action relative to that position wherever it sits across the space of the 3 screens.
That's the best way I can put it, does it make sense?

So, basically, I want to have the display extended across three monitors, but I want the touch input to match the point of that extended display that I actually click.

Actually, I could happily not have any touch on the second two screens - indeed I've tried disabling it. All I want is for the first screen to be the desktop and for my touch input to match the space on that screen that I touch.

Currently, if I were to touch the dead centre of the first screen, my 'click' would appear at the centre of the second screen (the centre of the full display).

I try and calibrate, but when it puts the crosshairs on the screen which you have to touch, the 'canvas' is spread across the three screens - but it will only accept the input from one of the screens, and display an error if you try to touch another.

The way Eyefinity seems to work is that it essentially tricks windows into thinking it's juse one monitor, so I only have the choice of one monitor to choose from, and so its sets the calibration across the dimensions of the whole 3 screens combined (5760 x 1080).

I wouldn't bother with Eyefinity, but I need to have the desktop extended across all 3 monitors, and as standard Windows only seems to allow you to do that across 2 monitors (and duplicate the other).

Does anybody have any ideas how I can solve this?